# unlocking working copy

Tags: svn

Somehow, I messed up my working copy and svn locked it.  I think it happened from moving a subdir and then moving it back without telling SVN about it.  Whenever I try to do something, SVN tells me my working copy is locked and that I need to run `svn cleanup` to remove it.  When I try that, SVN gives me this error:

```
svn: In directory '.'
svn: Error processing command 'modify-entry' in '.'
svn: Error modifying entry for 'bcrypt'
svn: 'bcrypt' is not under version control
```

( in my case the subdir is `bcrypt`)
I've looked at other SO questions, and can't seem to figure it out.  I tried deleting the `.svn/lock` file without any results.  I tried removing `bcrypt` and cleaning up but it still shows the same error message!  Here's my basic working copy structure:

```
Root (.)
    files...
    ...
    bcrypt
    .svn
```

I would greatly appreciate someone's help.
P.S. I've made a great  number of edits to my working copy so I would *much* rather not lose those if at all possible.

P.S.S. I'm using command-line svn on a mac

Comment: have you tried, copy the content, svn rm the file, svn update, paste the content into the file

Comment: I can't update.  I tried that or something similar but because it's locked it won't let me update.  Thanks though.

Comment: Just tried that.  It says that the working copy is locked and that I should run svn cleanup.  I even tried using --force.

Comment: ask the guy in charge of the repository (server side) to fix it, sorry I have no better

Comment: unfortunately, I own the repo.  Appreciate your help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15447/discussion-between-roine-and-harrison)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do in such a case, when you are worried for your working files, is to copy them elsewhere and delete the .svn metadata that goes with them. Then, checkout a fresh copy and overwrite it with your edited files. Then checkin.

Be careful of files that you have deleted from the working copy, but otherwise this always works - for all SCMs. Its also the safest that fiddling about trying to find the option to fix your wc, the worst case is that you end up deleting or overwriting all your work.